# Parse, filter nested XML in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a table (table1) which has a column containing XML data.
I need to parse that XML and create rows of data from the child elements of the element - 
The output needs to be something like
TestID  Sequence ParentSequence  ExtID   ExtName
-1          1        -1            1      ABC
-1          2        -1            1      DEF
-1          2        -1            1      GHI

But I am getting an empty result set with every other method I tried.
I have  focused on accessing Sequence as  rest will follow the same process.
Not sure why this does not work. Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thank you. The SQL I have tried is after the XML(commented text is the options I have tried)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
   DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmlfield 
   NVARCHAR(MAX));
   INSERT INTO @tbl (xmlfield) VALUES
   (N'<OBJECT CLASS="Test1" ID="-1" FULL="FULL" VERSION="1">
   <SUBTYPE NAME="SubType1">
      <OBJECT NAME="SubType111" ID="-1">
        <FIELD NAME="TestID">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="Sequence">1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ParentSequence">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ExtID">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ExtName">ABC</FIELD>

    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT NAME="SubType111" ID="-1">
        <FIELD NAME="TestID">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="Sequence">2</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ParentSequence">1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ExtID">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ExtName">DEF</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="__ExtendedData">&lt;OBJECT 
         CLASS="Meet123" ID="-1" FULL="FULL" 
         VERSION="1"&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="OrderDetailID"&gt;-1&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="OrderID"&gt;-1&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="Sequence"&gt;0&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="AttendeeID"&gt;123&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD NAME=" 
         AttendeeID _Name"&gt;Test, Mark/I H 6&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="ShowList"&gt;1&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="BdgeName"&gt;Mark&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="BadgeCompanyName"&gt;I H 6&lt;/FIELD&gt;
         &lt;/OBJECT&gt;</FIELD>
        </OBJECT>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT NAME="SubType111" ID="-1">
        <FIELD NAME="TestID">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="Sequence">3</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ParentSequence">1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ExtID">-1</FIELD>
        <FIELD NAME="ExtName">GHI</FIELD>
    </OBJECT>
  </SUBTYPE>
<SUBTYPE NAME="SubType2"/>
<SUBTYPE NAME="SubType3"/>
</OBJECT>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end


;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmlfield AS XML) AS cartxml
   FROM @tbl
)

SELECT ID
, c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="TestID"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS TestID
, c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="Sequence"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [Sequence]
, c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="ParentSequence"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS 
ParentSequence
, c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="ExtID"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ExtID
, c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="ExtName"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS 
 ExtName
 ,c1.value('(FIELD[@NAME="AttendeeID"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS 
 AttendeeId,
 ,c1.value('(FIELD[@NAME="AttendeeID_Name"]/text())[1]', 
 'VARCHAR(20)') AS AttendeeName,
 FROM src As T
 CROSS APPLY cartxml.nodes('/OBJECT/SUBTYPE/OBJECT[@ID="-1"]') as 
 t2(c)
 OUTER APPLY cartxml.nodes('/ 
 OBJECT/SUBTYPE/OBJECT[@ID="-1"]/FIELD[@NAME="__ExtendedData"]') as 
 t3(c1)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Hi @YitzhakKhabinsky, Thanks for the link.  I have added more information as much as possible. First post regarding XML hence may miss  a few details/guidelines. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmlfield NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmlfield) VALUES
(N'<OBJECT CLASS="Test1" ID="-1" FULL="FULL" VERSION="1">
    <SUBTYPE NAME="SubType1">
        <OBJECT NAME="SubType111" ID="-1">
            <FIELD NAME="TestID">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="Sequence">1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ParentSequence">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ExtID">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ExtName">ABC</FIELD>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NAME="SubType111" ID="-1">
            <FIELD NAME="TestID">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="Sequence">2</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ParentSequence">1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ExtID">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ExtName">DEF</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="__ExtendedData">&lt;OBJECT 
         CLASS="Meet123" ID="-1" FULL="FULL" 
         VERSION="1"&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="OrderDetailID"&gt;-1&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="OrderID"&gt;-1&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="Sequence"&gt;0&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="AttendeeID"&gt;123&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD NAME="AttendeeID_Name"&gt;Test, Mark/I H 6&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="ShowList"&gt;1&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="BdgeName"&gt;Mark&lt;/FIELD&gt;&lt;FIELD 
         NAME="BadgeCompanyName"&gt;I H 6&lt;/FIELD&gt;
         &lt;/OBJECT&gt;</FIELD>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NAME="SubType111" ID="-1">
            <FIELD NAME="TestID">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="Sequence">3</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ParentSequence">1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ExtID">-1</FIELD>
            <FIELD NAME="ExtName">GHI</FIELD>
        </OBJECT>
    </SUBTYPE>
    <SUBTYPE NAME="SubType2"/>
    <SUBTYPE NAME="SubType3"/>
</OBJECT>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmlfield AS XML) AS cartxml
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="TestID"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS TestID
    , c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="Sequence"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [Sequence]
    , c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="ParentSequence"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ParentSequence
    , c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="ExtID"]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ExtID
    , c.value('(FIELD[@NAME="ExtName"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS ExtName
    , w.value('(OBJECT/FIELD[@NAME="AttendeeID"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS AttendeeID
    , w.value('(OBJECT/FIELD[@NAME="AttendeeID_Name"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS AttendeeID_Name
FROM rs AS t
    CROSS APPLY cartxml.nodes('/OBJECT/SUBTYPE/OBJECT[@ID="-1"]') as t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CAST(c.query('FIELD[@NAME="__ExtendedData"]').value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS XML))) AS t2(w)
WHERE w.exist('/OBJECT[@CLASS="Meet123"]') = 1;
```

**Output**

| ID | TestID | Sequence | ParentSequence | ExtID | ExtName | AttendeeID | AttendeeID_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | 2 | 1 | -1 | DEF | 123 | Test, Mark/I H 6 |

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I have one more nested xml element in it. and it has &lt; &gt; instead of < >; Does that create problems when adding an OUTER APPLY ?

Comment: There are many reasons why it important to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please provide ##1-4. The idea is to copy it to SSMS and it will run as-is.

Comment: I have added the extra element in the original xml (<FIELD NAME="__ExtendedData">)   Pure beginner here. The xml is hundreds of lines and I am going through the requirements one level at a time. Also removing the original table name, etc. Therefore the q is coming in pieces. Expected output is to have 2 additional columns to the above output called AttendeeID and AttendeeName

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide ##1-4

Comment: You can use my answer **DDL and sample data population** section as a sample for the #1

Comment: Done - Added the code (from you example) I have used in the original Q

Comment: I don't see any T-SQL:` CREATE ..., INSERT ...`

Comment: The new chunk that was added is not a well-formed XML. You need to fix it.

Comment: Done. I also made sure to check it in online xml formatter..

Comment: The XML is still NOT well-formed

Comment: But I checked online and it said it is correct. Is it the &gt; &lt; tags?  That's how the xml is stored in the table

Comment: I had to make your XML well-formed. Please try it now

Comment: @vbgp, what's the latest?

Comment: Hi  @Yitzhak Khabinsky Perfect! This works flawlessly too. Just one Q before I close this. Is it possible to search as ExtendedData / Object Class = "Meet 123"?

Comment: @vbgp, Done. Check it out the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This worked  as well. Thank you very much. I may be posting more Qs (Updating, deleting XML) in the coming days; hoping to receive helpful answers from this fantastic community then as well.

Comment: @vbgp, Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as asnswer.

Comment: Also, please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0